# How to: Post Comment, not Answer

Tags: support, comments, answers-as-comments

I'm new to Stack Exchange.

I've noticed time and time again, questions get little "clarification requests" in a shaded blue directly beneath. These comments are clearly not posted answers, but I don't see how to post them myself. My options are "answer" or "suggest edit" (I'm on the mobile app). The first posts an answer, the latter asks for me to change the question's content.

Are those comments edit suggestions? Do I need to visit the full website?

Comment: You need 50 rep to comment on posts other than your own: http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment. Note that every site has a help centre, which contains all of this basic information.

Comment: Are you using the Android app or the iOS app?

Comment: I'm on the Android app. @jonrsharpe hit the nail on the head, though. I didn't know about the rep requirement and hadn't tried commenting on my own question yet. Thank you!

Comment: Quite possibly a duplicate; I did search around, but "comments" returns a lot of results. If this needs to be closed or the like, have at it. I'm satisfied! :)

Comment: I have to say, welcome to SE! Thanks for taking the time and being understanding about what happened, many new users don't. Good luck with your commenting!